# How can I publish a reusable react component into CDN?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, cdn, mui-x-data-grid

I have created a public react mui component - 'mui-datagrid-full-edit' and published on npm.

https://github.com/prettyblueberry/mui-datagrid-full-edit

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-datagrid-full-edit

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/prettyblueberry/mui-datagrid-full-edit-sample1

https://github.com/prettyblueberry/mui-datagrid-full-edit-sample1

Some developers want me to provide the component in CDN way. And I'm trying it but I don't know a right way for it.

So I searched to find a method to publish a reusable react component into CDN but I can't see a valuable examples or guides. Most says cdn is not recommended way for a reusable react component, and recommends npm.

But I believe it is not impossible and it can be provided on cdn like react core js files including react and react-dom.

Comment: Find a CDN host and follow the instructions they have perhaps?